# Is there a way to change a Google Account name/email?

Tags: google-api, google-account

I have ran into a problematic situation, which I really hope I can get help with.

I'm working on Jive Software solutions and we have a product that integrates Google Drive and Gmail.
This integration product was once part of a startup that was acquired by Jive and as such, the Google api project we are using for the integration belongs to a Google Account of a specific person which no longer works in Jive (we do have the credentials for the account though).

The problem is, that we want this account to be ours, i.e, a Jive software one.
So, one option I have, is to create a new account and replace the api account I'm using in the code to use the new one. This is bad, as it will break all the current authenticated clients, and will force them to take the oauth process all over again.

The other option I see, is to convert the existing Google account we are using to a jivesoftware one, so it will not be associated to any specific person but it will still be the same account.
Specifically I'm interesting in changing the Name and Email of this account.
Any suggestions of how we can achieve that?

A third option could be moving the api project to owned by another google account, but I couldn't find such an option in the UI, any clue?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to change a gmail address. You can forward all email to a new address with the name and email address you would like though.

This way you access all the email from an account that is a Jive software one but it is being forwarded from the old one still. However no one directly accesses the old one.

Check out https://support.google.com/mail/answer/10957?hl=en for more info.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/19870?hl=en), if you use Gmail with your Google Account, it's not currently possible to change your Gmail username after you've registered. with your username being the full email address you used to create your account. You can, however, change your nick name by going to https://myaccount.google.com and clicking Personal Info.

Comment: I'm not actively using gmail in this account, I only use this account for an api project which allows me to integrate to my customers gmail accounts.

Comment: Your email name is your user name for Google Accounts and according to the documentation you can't change it.